# Module for managing permissions on per node basis integrated with shopping cart or checkout

Tags: users

Hey I'm looking for a way to manage specific users access to specific nodes in Drupal. I'm wondering which modules I can use to accomplish this.

To elaborate:

Lets just say I have 20 stories on my site that cost 5$ each to access. Users need to sign up, and then they pay $5 for each story they want to have access to.

I need to manage the individual user's access to specific nodes automatically after they are paid for...

Anything you can point me toward would be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) module restricts users per node basis or per content type basis.

> This module allows you to manage permissions for content types by role
>   and author. It allows you to specifiy custom view, edit and delete
>   permissions for each content type. Optionally you can enable per
>   content access settings, so you can customize the access for each
>   content node.

You need to use commerce checkout hooks and Content Access API to achieve this. Try [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) modules too it may help with out using coding also.